# FCC Intermediate Algorithm Scripting: Pig Latin

Tags: javascript, string

This test objective is to take the first consonant (or consonant cluster) of an English word, moves it to the end of the word and suffixes an "ay". If a word begins with a vowel you just add "way" to the end.

My main issue is to iterate through the string until it reaches a vowel and put the first consonants letters to the end of the string.

I’m having trouble iterating through the string until it reaches a vowel. How do you iterate a string until it stops at the first vowel? How do you get all of the first consonant letters before it reaches vowel? I iterate the string by using the for loop, and I use the “if” statement if the first letters are consonant.

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  var vowel = /[aeiou]/g;
  var cons = /[^aeiou]/g;
  console.log(cons.test(str[2]))
  var consonants = [];
  var index = str.charAt(0);

  console.log(str.slice(1, str.length))
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    console.log(str[i])
    if(cons.test(str[i])){
      consonants.push(str.charAt(i));
      console.log(consonants)
      var slice = str.slice(consonants.length, str.length);
    }
  }
  return consonants + 'ay';
}
```

translatePigLatin("glove");

Comment: Do you want it to work just for words or for an entire sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would focus on just finding the index of the first vowel. Then you can test whether that index is 0 or something else. If it's zero, just add the `way` otherwise slice on that index:

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
  let ind = [...str.toLowerCase()].findIndex(s => vowels.includes(s))
  return ind 
         ? str.slice(ind) + str.slice(0, ind) + 'ay' // doesn't start with vowel
         : str + 'way'
}

console.log(translatePigLatin('glove'))
console.log(translatePigLatin('apple'))
console.log(translatePigLatin('Mark'))
console.log(translatePigLatin('Javascript'))
```

I'm not sure what the pig latin rules are for the edge case of a word with no vowels like `rhythm`.

Comment: The code above would not work for edgcases like words without any vowels.

Comment: @Michael -- that's a fair point. What is the correct behavior of a word like `crwth`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should break the problem into some basic cases, like I did in the code below:

1. Check if the first letter is a vowel; if true, just add 'way' to the end of the word and break the loop
2. If the current letter is a consonant (that means the first condition is not true), we just continue iterating
3. If the current letter is a vowel, we split the word into two separate parts and we add them on the other way around, not forgetting to ad the 'ay' suffix.

In the code below I also added to the vowels array the uppercase versions. With some modifications, it can be made to jump over delimiters. The Pig Latin rules were those I found on Wikipedia (although I did not find any rules for words only with consonants, so I put them in the first case).
Cheers!

```js
function has(a, e) {
    return a.indexOf(e) > -1;
}

function translateWord(str) {
    let vows = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
    vows = vows.concat(vows.map(v => v.toUpperCase()));

    let lastVowelIndex = 0;
    let conv = '';
    
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
        let currentChar = str[i];
        
        /* If the first character is a voewl, we just
         * add the 'way' suffix to the initial word.
         * I applied the same rule for words without
         * consonants.
         */
        if ((i === 0 && has(vows, currentChar))
            || (i === str.length - 1)) {
            conv = str + 'way';
            break;
        }
        
        /* If the current character is a consonant, we
         * just continue until we reach a vowel.
         */
        if (!has(vows, currentChar))
            continue;
        
        /* At this point, we reached a vowel, so we do the
         * appropriate transformations.
         */
        let firstPart =  str.slice(0, i);
        let secondPart = str.slice(i);
        
        conv = secondPart + firstPart + 'ay';
        break;
    }
    
    return conv;
}

function translateToPigLatin(str) {
    let words = str.split(' ');
    let converted = words.map(w => translateWord(w));
    
    return converted.join(' ');
}

let s = translateToPigLatin("I have no rythm");
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a RegExp?

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {
let res = '';

let regex = /[aeiou]/;

if (!regex.test(str)) {
  res = str + 'ay';
} else if (regex.test(str[0])) {
  res = str + 'way';
} else {
  let x  = str.indexOf(regex.exec(str)[0]);
  res = str.substr(x) + str.substr(0, x) + 'ay'
}
return res;
```

}